# Cross browser UI testing

Tags: testing, cross-browser

when we develop any website then it looks good at our end but client may view the page with different browser then he/she face problem. i search for tool or way by which i can view my pages from my local machine using different browser and different version. i found few web site provide this facility and saw they very slow and they are giving image of my page which i do not want rather i want to view my page in browser. so i want a tool which allow me to select browser and version and then show my page in that browser with specific version. i may change version and page should refresh for changing browser or version. i hope there must be many tool available but unfortunately i not getting right single one. can anyone guide me. thanks

Comment: Virtual machines may help here. But personally I prefer to use online services.

Comment: Thomas, please use proper capitalization in your posts. It should be "I", not "i", and sentences start with a capital letter. Also, make sure the tags are meaningful. `cross` by itself doesn't mean anything. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this related one has information on what you want to do, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298147/whats-the-best-way-to-test-cross-browser-compatibility?rq=1

Comment: Give him a break. This "duplicate" is 3 years old and things change quite rapidly in this space. Should we go back and answer old questions instead? I don't think so.

Comment: @cdonner This is not how it works though. To draw attention to old questions and ask for updated answers, one simply has to place a bounty. The OP could easily offer reputation for an up-to-date answer. The fact that the question is old doesn't make  it less of a duplicate.

Comment: @cdonner - Back when Stackoverflow was young I was admonished that YES, we were supposed to be going back and keeping answers current. That was part of the justification for letting people edit other people's questions and answers! This is one of a number of policy issues at the site I find a bit odd - just trying to provide a bit of "historical perspective." -shrug- I say "let a thousand flowers bloom." After all, who has time for all that question maintenance?!

Comment: may be my question looks odd but 3 yrs back there was but day-day technology change. i post it here if i got so any good ref for any tools which is free. it has no justification to give a negative mark. i often see here people like to give negative mark to other. not sure does they get any bonus for that or not??

Answer (score 0):

Adobe shut down BrowserLab a few weeks ago, but provided some guidance for other services that you can use on [this page](http://blogs.adobe.com/browserlab/2013/03/13/browserlab-is-shutting-down-on-march-13-2013/). There there are the [Spoon.net browser sandboxes](http://spoon.net/browsers/), but it installs the VM on your computer and I never liked that.

I personally use VMWare virtual machines with olders versions of IE on Windows, and Safari on a Mac VM. A little more effort to set this up, but I find it works best.